# How to use resource id in Appium

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, appium, android-testing

I am testing a mobile app which doesn't have right set locators in it, so i can use only "resource-id"

```
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

# Locators

profile_btn = (AppiumBy.ID, 'io.dzain.dzain.uat:id/navItemIV')
profile_btn.click()
```

When I run this code following error message is displayed
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'click'

How can i use the resource-id to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You call clicks on the appium/webdriver elements returned from the driver, something like so:

```
profile_btn = self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ID, 'io.dzain.dzain.uat:id/navItemIV')
profile_btn.click()
```

You feed your by method and your element locator definition into the find_element function and call clicks on the element object it returns to you.